# Setting up batch file to run on command line, setting up shop

Tags: java

I just installed the into the defaulta location C:\Program Files and wanted a batch file to start when I start a new cmd in Windows XP.  My batch file is:

```
@echo off
SET TOOLS_HOME=%ProgramFiles%\Java
SET JAVA_HOME=%TOOLS_HOME%\jdk1.6.0_21
SET PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\BIN;%PATH%
SET CLASSPATH=.;
```

This file is in Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin

From there, I created a shortcut for my cmd-line, and I used the /k in target so that looks like:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe /k %ProgramFiles%\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin\setenv.bat
```

And my Start in: is %HOMEDRIVE%

When I then start my command prompt, I get 'c:\Program\ is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.  Is my batch file correct?  Or is my Target/Start in incorrect?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `""` around the param line such as:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe /k "%ProgramFiles%\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin\setenv.bat"
```